# Dragon Age: Origins - Strength modifier vs damage

Tags: dragon-age-origins

I got one question. I just found two 2-handed weapons:

1. Battleaxe (Red Steel) tier 5
   Damage: 14.00
   Strength Modifier: 1.10
2. Maul (Veridium) Tier 4
   Damage: 11.70
   Strength Modifier: 1.25

Character Strength: **32**

My question is, what is Strength Modifier? Which weapon is better in terms of damage? I am thinking of testing both weapons, but armor penetration stat makes the difference, so I still won't be sure, its better to have high modifier, or higher weapon damage.

Comment: I do not know the formula, but the higher the tier is the better the weapon.

Comment: I know that. But what if both weapons, axe and maul were same tier? Still maul would have lover dmg, but higher modifier :P

Comment: They are not, part of your question is which of the two is better at damage. It's 1. Battleaxe. If you know that do not ask ;)

Comment: But isn't strength used also to count dmg? If it is, then strength modifier might influence damage output.. Thats what i am trying to learn, if this makes any difference.

Comment: According to gamefaqs it does only add to the "to hit" roll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This if the formula that comes from the wiki, it's a hit probability formula.

```
 AttackValue = 55 + 0.5 * {(Strength - 10) + (Dexterity - 10)} + AttackBonuses
```

They did not clarify what the 55 + 0.5 means so an exact calculation i can not make for you. As you can see it takes strength into the calculation and if a weapon has a higher strength modifier you have more chance to land an physical attack.

If i would know how to make html tables on this site or have any other way of formatting my text i would put up a table with the actual values what chance an attack has to hit an opponent. Might figure that out later and edit this but for now check out: http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Combat_mechanics